# Issue with filestream, reading line by line. ENONET thrown, despite file existing

Tags: node.js

I'm having issues with a function that reads a text file line by line. It says the file I'm trying to read does not exist, although it does in the file path I am running node on. What could be the issue??

```
function insertUsers(auth) {
fs.readFile('emails.txt', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var person = data.toString().split("\n");

var person = data.toString().split("\n");
for (var i = 0; i < person.length(); i++) {
    service.members.insert({
        groupKey: 'testgroup@x.com',
        resource: {
            email: person[i],
            role: 'MEMBER',
        }

    }, (err, res) => {
        if (err) { return console.error('The API returned an error:', err.message); }

        const user = res.data.member;

        if (member.length) {
            write_log('Inserted' + email + ' into student group.');
        } else {
            write_log('Failed to delete ' + email);
        }
    });
    }
});
```

}
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UTK6.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVvnA.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was due to how I made emails.txt. The name is "emails.txt", and the file extension is .txt. I changed the file name to "emails", and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you're starting your node application from the same location where your file (emails.txt) is. According to your method logic it should be

```
C:\Users\[]\source\repos\StudentGroups\StudentGroups > node main.js
```

you can check the current working directory from the code

```
console.log(process.cwd())
```

it should be

```
C:\Users\[]\source\repos\StudentGroups\StudentGroups
```

Otherwise, modify your code to correctly point to the email.txt or start your application from the correct directory.

Comment: that's exactly what it is. how would the string be if I wanted to have it directly point?

Comment: When you say directly point, do you mean fs.readFile('C:\\Users\\[]\\source\\repos\\StudentGroups\\StudentGroups\\emails.txt' ... ?